# a puzzle of symbols (Close to each other)

Tags: visual

Can you fill in the empty squares with the Correct symbols? Explain your reasoning.

[image]

Comment: Just want to add... no knowledge required other than trivial. And the squares are not part of the puzzle.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the completed series looks like this:

> [image: CI CV CX CL CC CD CM]

Why?

> If you rotate the image by 90° clockwise you can see that the symbols are two letters run together without gap ("close to each other", as the title says): CI, CL, CC and CD. These letters are, of course, the Roman numerals: The first letter is always C, the second letters are all Roman numerals in ascending order.
>
>  So the whole sequence should be CI, **CV**, **CX**, CL, CC, CD, **CM**.
>
>  (The corresonding numbers are 101, 105, 110, 150, 200, 400 and 900, but I don't think that's important here. The gimmick is that the puzzle looks like a series of geometrical symbols, IQ test style.)

Comment: Great job! Yes, that was my intention, to make it look like an IQ puzzle (so the corresponding numbers are indeed not important here)

Answer (score 5):

My solution was not quite identical with M Oehm's. The first six boxes are the same, but the last is

> [image], i.e. [DI] rotated.

> The rationale is that these are the first seven three-digit numbers with two-character roman numerals.

Comment: Nice answer! Didn't think of that